# issue using string resource in android which is a html entity

Tags: android, string, html-entities

ok so my app has maths stuff in it and as a result I use various mathematical symbols. I have various hardcoded strings which pull through placeholders and also render the html entity code to the appropriate symbol

e.g. This one when called with the appropriate text fillers and the HTML entity showing as a symbol

```
<string name="multiQ_normal_alt1">(%1$d &#xd7; %2$d) &#xd7; %3$d</string>
```

I also have strings which only have the symbol which I am just starting to use and I am running into some issues

e.g.

```
<string name="multi_symbol">&#xd7;</string>
```

Now when I try to call this string it sees the contents as an Int (which doesnt happen with the version above). I am forced to make it a string if I want to show it in my text view and I get a 10 digit code such as 2131689610 instead of it rendering the symbol (It doesnt even output the html entity code ×)

```
private var SUMTYPECODE = ""
SUMTYPECODE = R.string.multi_symbol.toString()}
SumTypeItemView.text = SUMTYPECODE
```

I would love to solve this by myself if I can still but I am completely thrown by the code that comes out as I cant even find what sort of code it is, I mean I assumed maybe some serial number but searching across google isnt giving me many meaningful results

Are HTML entities in strings bad practice? Is there a better way? Am I missing something really obvious?

*I appreciate I have not shared much actual code and will share anything required to assist but unless I am mistaken its just the string resource and calls to it that's needed. Plus the setting of the view,text just in case (view variable was set earlier in the code - no issues reaching the view)

Comment: `R.string.multi_symbol` is just the id of the string resource. You need to use `Context#getString(int resourceId)` to get the actual string

Comment: @JensV thank you (silly me). I am in an adaptor so context isn't recognised and getString wont import. But I will work on that problem separately

Comment: One usually needs these resources in `inflateLayout`, where the LayoutInflater has a context for your use. (Or you just pass the context when creating the adapter)

Comment: @JensV I used a context within the adapter yes and ended with the following final snippet: myContext.resources.getString(R.string.multi_symbol)

Comment: In an adapter, you can catch any non-null view, and get context with `myView.getContext()` or `myView.context` in Kotlin